# How to print from a different IP address on a different subnet?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, printer, gateway

I have two internal networks:

`172.xxx.xxx.xxx`, this is a wireless network, and the devices on this network are not able to print to the printer on the other network.

I have another network that is `10.0.xxx.xxx`, and the devices on the `172.xxx.xxx.xxx` network have been able to print to the `10.0.xxx.xxx`. printer in the past, but for some reason just recently there's no connectivity between them. I cannot ping the `172.xxx.xxx.xxx` devices from the `10.0.xxx.xxx` network and visa versa.

I am far from an expert on this, though I am a programmer.

What is the terminology of this type of situation where you want to print to a completely different IP address?

What steps do I have to take in order to identify the source of the issue?

I do know that the printer has a gateway of `10.0.6.254` address, and ip address of `10.1.0.99`, and I know this because I was able to check the settings of the printer itself using its own hardware.

The following is an example of a computer that is able to print this printer:

[image]

the following is an example that is NOT able to connect to the printer:

[image]

Comment: Can you ping the printer when you disable you wireless interface? It appears that the printer is not within the same subnet as the PC from the pictures. If you have a DHCP server try changing the ip settings to accept DHCP on the printer if they are not already. I think the IP being in a different subnet may be causing the problem. Can we get all the IP settings of the printer?

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. sorry i am not at the location right now, but i kjown that the printer has set itself a static ip of something like 10.1.10.99 and the gateway is 10.0.6.254

Comment: @JakeGould thank you. i believe everything was working fine just a few days ago.... could it be possible that that "bridge" was simply a router that wireleslly connected the two netwokrs?

Comment: What provides the routing on your LAN? You've got two separate subnets and, without routes from your 172. to 10. network then this won't work. What's your office router/firewall? This needs to be configured to allow print (and ICMP for ping) from one subnet to another.

Comment: could it be possible that that "bridge" was simply a router that wireleslly connected the two netwokrs?

Comment: how would i see all the routes on the netwrok?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a route issue on the router or a firewall access rules. Please make sure to add a route for 10.x.x.x and 172.x.x.x subnet vice versa on the directly connected router and also allow the access between these two subnets.

If you are using a Wireless AP, login to the AP and check for the route / firewall access rules settings.

Do a tracert from the windows machine and find the last reachable IP and this will isolate the issue. Make sure to turn-off the windows firewall if you are pining windows machine.

Let me know if this solves the issue. These are the RCA steps which will solve related issues.